# How to get the time taken for Pod to boot up using Promethus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I need to get the time taken by a pod to boot up from Pod Scheduled to Pod running status using Prometheus metrics.

I understand these information are avaiable in kubectl pod commands, but need to get as part of promql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [pod metrics from kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/pod-metrics.md). There is a ton of valuable information there.

For this specific case, I think that `kube_pod_container_state_started` and `kube_pod_status_scheduled_time` could be of interest to you:

> From the kube-state-metrics docs:
>
> - `kube_pod_status_scheduled_time`: Unix timestamp when pod moved into scheduled status
> - `kube_pod_container_state_started`: Start time in unix timestamp for a pod container.

The difference between these metrics should provide the amount of time that a pod was scheduled but not yet running.